# Inline onclick handler preventing catch form's submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, submit

I have the following inline code that I can't change due is outputted by a foreigner plugin. Contain a `onclick` handler that trigger the `submit` event:

```
<input type='button' id='gform_next_button_12_188' 
class='button gform_next_button' value='Next' tabindex='3' 
onclick='jQuery("#gform_target_page_number_12").val("2"); jQuery("#gform_12").trigger("submit",[true]); '/>
```

I want to run some routines before submit the form and I tried this:

```
$("#gform_12").submit(function(e){

    // this code is not running ...

});
```

That it is failing, ie, my code is not running when form is submitted . Any suggest?

**Final solution based on answers given**

```
var inline_onclick_code_on_next = $(".gform_next_button").first().attr("onclick");
$(".gform_next_button").removeAttr("onclick");
$(".gform_next_button").bind("click", function() {
    myClass.autosave_on_click(inline_onclick_code_on_next);
});

myClass = {
    errorMessage : "",
    autosave_on_click: function (inline_onclick_code){
        my_gravity_form_saving_running = 1;
        myClass.saveData(); // this code must put my_gravity_form_saving_running = 0 when all data be saved
        countdown_max_loop = 10; // seconds
        var countdown = window.setInterval(function(){
            if (countdown_max_loop-- == 0 || my_gravity_form_saving_running == 0){
                clearInterval(countdown);
                eval (inline_onclick_code);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is failing? what happens? Do you want the form to submit but it doesn't?

Comment: My code is not running when form is submitted.

Comment: I believe that without a fiddle reproducing it you won't (good) answers. :(

Comment: @gdoron this is part of a WP plugin. It works in localhost, just fail in the client's online site. And it is a password protected site! (this site have about 30 plugins running!) :(

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2fC4j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unbind the click event from the element and then specify your own.

```
$('#gform_next_button_12_188').unbind('click').removeAttr('onclick');
$('#gform_next_button_12_188').bind('click', function() {
    // do magic stuff

    // do the rest
    jQuery("#gform_target_page_number_12").val("2");
    jQuery("#gform_12").trigger("submit",[true]); 
});
```

Edit:

added removeAttr, thanks @gdoron

Comment: +1 thanks gdoron and ilanco. `removeAttr()` it is the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to unbind the click method, and then rebind what you want to do instead:

```
$('#gform_next_button_12_188')
   .unbind('click')
   .bind('click', function() {
       // your stuff
       // submit stuff that was there
   });
```

**Edit:** try this instead to override the onclick attribute:

```
$('#gform_next_button_12_188')
  .attr('onclick', '')
  .bind('click', function() {
      // your stuff
      // submit stuff that was there
  });
```

Comment: You meant he is a fiddle to show your edit works. anyway I'm pretty sure that it's not what the needs.

Comment: @Sam - Your jsFiddle doesn't use `unbind()`.  It uses `removeAttr()`.  This jsFiddle shows that `unbind()` doesn't work on inline handlers:  http://jsfiddle.net/nbmkc/3/

Answer (score 1):

It would be convenient to be able to prepend your stuff without having to retype (or even to know) the inline stuff.

The following function will do this:

```
$(function(){
    function prependHandler(selector, event, fn) {
        try {
            if (event.split(' ').length > 1) {
                event = event.split(' ')[0];
            }
            var $el = $(selector),
                inline_handler = $el.get(0)['on' + event];
            $el.on(event, function() {
                fn.call(this); //invoke your own magic stuff
                inline_handler.call(this); //invoke original inline magic stuff
            }).get(0)['on' + event] = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //call as follows:
    prependHandler("#gform_next_button_12_188", 'click', function() {
        alert('my functionality'); //specify your own magic stuff here
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNcBp/2/)

Notes:

- In `prependHandler`, we use `.call(this)` to ensure that `this` (a reference to the target element) is available as `this` inside the original handler and the prepended handler, in case it's needed.
- `prependHandler` returns true or false to allow you to test whether it was successful or not, in case you need to know.
- Whereas you could pass in a selector that selects multiple elements, the use of `.get(0)` internally limits `prependHandler` to working on the first selected element.
- With a litle more thought you could frame `prependHandler` as a jQuery plugin to overcome the above limitation but it will work fine as it is on a single element.

Comment: +1 Yes, you right. In fact I already coded a `Final solution based on answers given` that takes in account `unknown` onclick content. Thanks.-

Comment: $NomikOS, I just edited my notes so you might like to read them again. The point I make about multiple selectors may also apply to your own final solution.

Comment: Thanks! My code is working now, but your suggested code is very good!